# Does Google Analytics have browser console protection? If not, what to do?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm experimenting with Google Analytics and I wondered... what if someone decides to mess with it through the browser console?

I have a property in GA and I typed

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) ga('send', 'pageview');
```

in the Google Chrome console while looking at the Real-Time reports tab for that property. It showed me that 10 new visitors came. Isn't this really bad? Anyone with basic JavaScript skills can cause a serious problem.

I am a bit afraid to check what happens with a `10000` iteration loop because I don't want to mess up my tracking data. Is GA going to ignore such a thing or perhaps throw some kind of warning?

**Is there any form of protection for stuff like that? If not, what is the best thing to do in order to protect my data?**

Comment: Basically, the owner of the site is the one who places the tracking code. If you want to get good measurements, you won't mess with the code. If you are concerned about site users providing malicious inputs then GA is the least of your concerns.

Comment: I have a static site and GA is my _only_ concern. It's a bit silly that a single person can mess up everything and I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. There is a limit on how many hits you can send in a [certain timeframe](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas):

> Each analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are
>   replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second. Applies to all hits except
>   for ecommerce (item or transaction).

The javascript code will throttle down the requests to meet that limit. However spammers do not even need to go to your website, they can just as well send hits via the measurement protocol which will not be throttled. Or someone can simply copy the Ga request from the network console, paste it to the browser and hit reload a hundred times.

I don't think protection would be feasible in any way. There is nothing secret about the data you sent, everything from the Google Analytics endpoint to the tracking id is visible in the browser. There is no real way to know if a request is genuine or malicious.

You could try a javascript solution - write a GA plugin that drops pageview requests if the URL has not changed, or one that implements stricter rules for throttling - but that would not change the fact that someone could simple ping the GA endpoint with your tracking id and have a lot of pageviews registered.

However given that GA has been around for eleven years now and people are still using it this does not seem to be a big problem. If you see big spikes (e.g. by bots or crawlers) there is some combination of dimensions that allows you to build a segment that hides the offending user in the reports.